# How to add an extension method to the MessageBox

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods

it's possible?

based in another's examples, as LabelExtesios, StringExtensions, etc.
I wrote this:

```
namespace MessageBoxExtensions
{

    public static class MessageBoxExtensionsClass
    {
        public static void Foo()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

then:

```
using MessageBoxExtensions;
// ... 

MessageBox.Foo();
```

gin an error:  MessageBox.Foo();

```
'System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox' does not contain a definition for 'Foo'
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Description

**You cant do this because `System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox`** is **NOT** an instance of `MessageBox`. `MessageBox.Show()` is a static method.

You cant create an instance of `MessageBox` because this class has no public constructor.

### Update

But you can create your own class in the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace and use the
`MessageBox` in this method like this

### Sample

```
namespace System.Windows.Forms
{
    public static class MyCustomMessageBox
    {
        public static void Foo()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("MyText");
        }
    }
}

MyCustomMessageBox.Foo();
```

Comment: Yes, extension methods cannot be defined at the static scope, so 1up from me!

Comment: Where is your 1up for me ? ;) just kidding

Comment: not worked for me: Error 1 The type `'System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox' has no constructors defined`

Comment: Then, it is not possible... :( I'II accept your answer. Thanks very much!

Comment: @dknaack, sorry dodgy mobile internet. +1 now ;-)

Comment: +2 if I could, what a nightmare I was having!

Answer (score 4):

You are missing the [this keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311042.aspx) from your extension method declaration.
But because `System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox` does not have a public constructor just static factory methods (which returns `DialogResult`) so you won't able the create a standalone `MessageBox` instance to invoke your extension method on it.

So to answer the your question:
Yes it's possible to create an extension method on `MessageBox` (see other answers) but you can't invoke it by `MessageBox.Foo()` you need an instance of `MessageBox` what you cannot create so it won't work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a parameter of type `MessageBox` to the extension method:

```
public static void Foo(this MessageBox messageBox) { ... }
```

Then create an instance of the MessageBox before calling the method

```
var messageBox = new MessageBox();
messageBox.Foo();
```

*[Update:
Unfortunately this doesn't work in case of the `MessageBox` since there is no public constructor. Thanks to **nemesv** for the hint. The following example should theoretically work, but in practice it won't. I'll leave it for reference.]*

In your example you call the method on the class itself. Extension methods only apply to instances. Here's a version of your code with the above corrections applied:

```
namespace MessageBoxExtensions
{
    public static class MessageBoxExtensionsClass
    {
        public static void Foo(this MessageBox messageBox)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}

using MessageBoxExtensions;
// ... 
var messageBox = new MessageBox();
messageBox.Foo();
```

Comment: What you have wrote is true, but `System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox` does not have a public constructor so it won't work.

Comment: Yes, thank you for the hint. Sometimes I wonder if Microsoft ever thought about OO principles before creating Winforms...

Answer (score 0):

You must qualify the extension method parameter with a `this` modifier for it to be registered as an extension method.

```
namespace MessageBoxExtensions
{
    public static class MessageBoxExtensionsClass
    {
        public static void Foo(this MessageBox messagebox)
        {

        }
    }
}
```